# InDesign: Double Overbar

Tags: adobe-indesign, mathematics

I'm trying to finish a chapter on Boolean algebra and digital logic.  I've constructed overbars by displacing the underline up above the character as explained in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/138695/154671) by Lucian., and that seems to work well. Now I need a double overbar, that is, something that looks like an = sign perched above a letter.

The font in Minion Pro, which does not have combining diacritics.

There is a double underline, but the strokes are too thin and too close together.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: you can allways make your own font that has the specal features you need. then just typeset by adding a character from that font. in this xase the font would have the combining character only.

Comment: @joojaa I've looked at font editing applications, but never used one.  I am not averse to learning new things, but I'm also working against a deadline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inline graphics.

[image]

The upper item is a group which contains a textframe which includes letter B. The group has also 2 drawn lines. I call it temporarily "Yes(B)".

Below it there's a text frame which contains expression A+B and some random text.

The blue rectangle is a separate item. It's a reference to show how the lines are moved in the next edit:

[image]

Letter B is replaced by selecting it and pasting the group Yes(B).

Yes(B) is editable in the text:

[image]

Unfortunately only changing the letter is easy. If you want to insert a longer text you must stretch the text frame and the lines manually. Fortunately there's no need to ungroup for it.

Comment: Thank you!  I now have a paragraph that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfauJ.png

Comment: @BobBrown Another common way to present the negation is to put the expression in brackets and to insert an apostrophe. Before DTP and math typesetting software it was the way to type readable boolean expressions.

Comment: Check.  However, this is a text for beginning students, and I don't want to confuse them with alternate notations.

Comment: This is the complicated, improvised version :)

Comment: @Lucian I actually tried that first.  The double-underline's strokes are too thin and too close together.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Character Style and use the Underline Options, adjust the settings similar to the (first image below), negative offset moves the underline above, you have a few Type presets, and then apply this style where needed.

Everything remains completely editable, you are not breaking the text flow and the style can apply to as many characters as you need with no extra effort. Just select and apply.

```
Answer completed with the help of @Wolff:
```

You can change the stroke width in the Character Style to make it bolder. Besides that, you can create your own Stroke Styles using the Stroke panel, click the sandwich menu and choose Stroke Styles. Here you can define a stroke style that fits your needs (second image below).

---

(image 1)

[image]

---

(image 2)

[image]

Comment: I think this is by far the best solution, Bob. You can change the stroke width in the Character Style to make it bolder. Besides that, are you aware that you can create your own Stroke Styles? In the Stroke panel, click the sandwich menu and choose Stroke Styles. Here you can define a stroke style that fits your needs. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/9SKvpWf.png). (Perhaps you should add this information to the answer, Lucian?)

Comment: Thanks buddy, edited. It is very much the best solution. I was actually amused to read the other answer, as I have worked with INDD files from people that improvise like that, and put tape on it until it holds, like its Office 1999.